# How to get the character/role names of actors in the Neo4j Movie Database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the neo4j movie database and I need to obtain the role names of actors in a particular movie. I have tried this command:

```
MATCH (wallstreet:Movie { title: 'Wall Street' })<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor)
RETURN actor.roles
```

but this command just returns null. The following screenshot shows that "roles" exist in the properties but I still can't make it work. What query should I use for this purpose?
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If it's from the movie db that is shipped with Neo4j, you should try this query instead :

```
MATCH (:Movie { title: 'Wall Street' })<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(actor:Person)
RETURN actor.name, r.roles
```

Comment: I am not using the shipped version, but instead I am using the version available at https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/. And this command is still not working. It return null for r.roles.

Comment: are you sure that this database includes the actor's roles ? I can't find it on the documentation ....

Comment: I will post a screenshot in my question. In the properties shown on the left panel, the third last line contains "roles".

Answer (score 0):

The role names are located on the edges between the actor node and the movie node. The following command return the role names:

```
MATCH (actor:Person {name: {name}})-[roles:ACTS_IN]->(movies) RETURN movies,roles
```